# Flyway and QuestDB: unknown function name: EXISTS(CURSOR)

Tags: java, flyway, questdb

I am trying to run Flyway migrations scripts on QuestDB.

When I run it I get the following error:

```
 ERROR: unknown function name: EXISTS(CURSOR)
```

I see from the logs that it sends this query to QuestDB which obviously doesn't implement EXISTS(CURSOR) even though they promise to implement PostgreSQL's interface.

```sql
select-virtual EXISTS((select-virtual 1 1 from (select [relnamespace, relname, relkind] from pg_catalog.pg_class() c join (select [oid, nspname] from pg_catalog.pg_namespace() n 
where nspname = $1) n on n.oid = c.relnamespace where relname = $2 and relkind = 'r') c)) EXISTS from (long_sequence(1))
```

We use Flyway company-wide so I am trying to make it work. Does anyone have ideas on how I can stop flyway to make this query? Or anything else that would help?

Answer (score 1):

QuestDB implements postgreSQL wire protocol compatibility for queries, but it doesn't implement the whole of PostgreSQL metadata or functions.

What this means is you can send your QuestDB SQL query using a postgreSQL driver (jdbc, psychopg...) and get your results back, but unfortunately if the statement makes reference to schemas or metadata it will probably fail.

There are some open issues about implementing more PostgreSQL metadata compatibility, specifically to be compatible with SQLAlchemy and open QuestDB to many existing tools.

You can find a list of those issues at [QuestDB's github](https://github.com/questdb/questdb/labels/Compatibility). Since those target mostly Python integration and Flyway uses JAVA, I added [a new issue](https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues/2681) to track your request